# unable to send data from form to firestore database in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time using firestore and I have a register form to send username , email , password to register a user using firebase authentification . The problem is that after creating a user I want to create  a username to link to that user . With my approach below I get the error  :

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

and my user is not registered . Without the username addition to firestore my user is created succesfully but it seems that there is a memory leak while trying to register which I do not understand why and I need a cleanup function that I do not know how to implement .

My code :

```
import React, { createContext , useContext ,useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import {auth} from '../firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
 
  const [user,setUser] = useState('');
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email,password,username){ //this is where my error lies while trying to insert user to firestore collection of users 
    return ()=> { 
      auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(()=>{
          firebase.firestore().collection('users').add({
           userName:username
         })
      })
      
    };
  }

  function signin(email,password){
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
  }

  function logout(){
    return auth.signOut();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
      setUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    })

    return unsubscribe;
    //how can I use cleanup function here ? 
  }, []);
  
  const info = {
    user,
    signin,
    signup,
    logout
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value = {info}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
  
}

  export function useAuth(){
   return useContext(AuthContext);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest separating the context and the firestore call, see an example:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      setPending(false)
    });
  }, []);

  const userContext = {
    currentUser,
  };

  if(pending){
    return <>Loading...</>
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={
        userContext
      }
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And in Firebase.js for example use:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const usersRef = db.collection('users');

export const doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = async (pEmail, pPassword, pUsername) => {
    const authResult = await app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(pEmail, pPassword);
    usersRef.doc(authResult.user.uid)
        .set({
            created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            email: pEmail,
            username: pUsername,
        });
}
```